# Private npm package fails to install with `npm ci` , but works with `npm i` why?

Tags: node.js, npm, uwebsockets

I have this package in my `package.json`:   `"uWebSockets.js": "github:uNetworking/uWebSockets.js#v18.9.0",`

when trying to install this package within docker with `npm i` -> works

but with `npm ci` i get: `npm ERR! Host key verification failed`

First of all, would like to know what is the difference.

second, if I can get help on how to do CI within the docker file.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but here is a work around, taken from [this github issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2610#issuecomment-795189708):

> For the benefit of anyone looking for a workaround who struggled to
> understand the conversation above, if you are installing something
> from a public github repo and want to force https, this should work:
>
> ```
> npm install git+https://<githubUsername>@github.com/<project>/<repo>.git
> ```
>
> It potentially doesn't matter what github username you use, because
> everyone can access public repos. The use of the username qualifies as
> 'auth' and therefore forces the protocol to be kept, as explained in
> point 2 in [#2610 (comment)](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2610#issuecomment-780761122).